# Check if same fields are empty in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-selectors

The title makes this seem simple, I tried googling around but I'm not even certain how to phrase what I'm attempting to do.

I have a set of fields that look like so

```
<tr>
   <td><strong>File Label:</strong></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="label[]" id="label" class="label" /></td>
   <td><strong>Student File (pdf):</strong></td>
   <td><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="file" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><strong>File Label:</strong></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="label[]" id="label" class="label" /></td>
   <td><strong>Student File (pdf):</strong></td>
   <td><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="file" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><strong>File Label:</strong></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="label[]" id="label" class="label" /></td>
   <td><strong>Student File (pdf):</strong></td>
   <td><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="file" /></td>
</tr>
```

As you see, `label[]` and `file[]` repeat.

How, using jQuery can I make sure that at least 1 `label` and 1 `file` are NOT empty/null before I allow the form to submit.

I attempted this, but it failed

```
$('.label').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
      alert('Stop Form');
   }
   else
   {
      alert('Submit Form');
   }
});
```

Comment: You should always use unique IDs. If you dont, your code might work now, but it could cause lots of trouble later.

Comment: The id's will repeat anyhow, as only 1 <tr> exists... the rest get's added via jquery to repeat the fields as many times as a user needs.

Comment: Then add an incrementing number to the `id`, or use a `class`-name. An `id` '[***must*** be unique within the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)' (***emphasis*** mine).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('[name="label[]"]').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() }).length >0
```

If you want to check for a couple of name/file (i.e. in the same tr), then you can do

```
var notEmptyTr = $('tr').filter(function(){
    return $('[name="label[]"]', this).val() && $('[name="file[]"]', this).val()
});
```

and then check `notEmptyTr.length>0`.

Comment: This works great! I'll have to read up on the .filter(). Thanks very much!